# Using Multithreading with Threshold to Sort an Array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, java-threads

It is my first time posting a question. So please, go easy on me. :D

I am a student and I currently learning about multithreading.

My task is to determine the sorting of an array by dividing the array into two equal halves and
start a thread for each half, each thread being responsible for sorting the numbers assigned to it.

The thread is looking at how many numbers need to be sorted. If this is more than
a certain threshold, the thread will create 2 new threads, each sorting one half of the list. When those
threads are finished, the thread will merge the two (sorted) arrays together again. This creates a 'tree'
of active threads.

Threads that are not going to 'outsource' their work sort the arrays again with bubble sort

This is my code for the MultiThreading class:

```
public class MultiThreading implements Runnable {

    private int[] wholeNumbers;
    private int threshold;

    public int[] getWholeNumbers() {
        return wholeNumbers;
    }

    public MultiThreading(int[] wholeNumbers, int threshold) {
        this.wholeNumbers = wholeNumbers;
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sortArray(wholeNumbers, threshold);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public int[] sortArray(int[] wholeNumbers, int threshold) throws InterruptedException {
        if (wholeNumbers.length < threshold) {
            Sort.bubbleSort(wholeNumbers);
        } else {
            int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(wholeNumbers, 0, wholeNumbers.length / 2);
            int[] right =  Arrays.copyOfRange(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length / 2, wholeNumbers.length);

            Thread leftThread = new Thread(new MultiThreading(left, threshold));
            Thread rightThread = new Thread(new MultiThreading(right, threshold));

            leftThread.start();
            rightThread.start();

            leftThread.join();
            rightThread.join();

            wholeNumbers = Sort.merge(left,right);
        }

        return wholeNumbers;
    }
}
```

This is how I initialize the class (here I try to change an already defined wholeNumbers array):

```
                    MultiThreading multiThreading = new MultiThreading(wholeNumbers, threshold);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(multiThreading);
                    thread.start();
                    thread.join();

                    wholeNumbers = multiThreading.getWholeNumbers();
```

I have been provided with the sorting and merging method, so they work just fine.

My problem is that it does not return the sorted array. I am not sure how to fix that.

It would be great if I receive some guidance. Thanks in advance.

---

**SOLUTION**

It turned out that the values in the merge method are not the correct ones that I should have used.

To fix this problem, I initialized the MultiThreading class two times, added them to the Threads, and used a get method in the merging function.
By doing that I ensure that the merging method receives the bubble-sorted whole numbers.

Here is my new Multithreading class:

```
public class MultiThreading implements Runnable {
    private int[] wholeNumbers;
    private int threshold;

    public int[] getWholeNumbers() {
        return wholeNumbers;
    }

    public void setWholeNumbers(int[] wholeNumbers) {
        this.wholeNumbers = wholeNumbers;
    }

    public MultiThreading(int[] wholeNumbers, int threshold) {
        this.wholeNumbers = wholeNumbers;
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (wholeNumbers.length > threshold) {
            int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(wholeNumbers, 0, wholeNumbers.length / 2);
            int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(wholeNumbers, wholeNumbers.length / 2, wholeNumbers.length);

            MultiThreading leftM = new MultiThreading(left, threshold);
            MultiThreading rightM = new MultiThreading(right, threshold);

            Thread leftThread = new Thread(leftM);
            Thread rightThread = new Thread(rightM);

            leftThread.start();
            rightThread.start();

            try {
                leftThread.join();
                rightThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            setWholeNumbers(Sort.merge(leftM.getWholeNumbers(), rightM.getWholeNumbers()));
        }
        else {
            Sort.bubbleSort(wholeNumbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code in the main class:

```
MultiThreading multiThreading = new MultiThreading(wholeNumbers, threshold);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(multiThreading);
                    thread.start();
                    thread.join();
                    wholeNumbers = multiThreading.getWholeNumbers();
```

I should learn to use a pen and paper, understand the logic and then code.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/995891

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @zapl I retrieve an unsorted array using the get method. That is my issue. I should have specified it earlier.

Comment: Ok, where is your code going wrong then? Put some print statements in it and figure out what part isn't working as expected

Comment: You should decide for one policy and use it consistently A) the method is supposed to change the specified array (then, it is not required to return it), or B) the method is supposed to create a new, sorted array and return it (then, the caller must use the return value). In either case, having a field and a parameter of the same name is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and for your help. I have actually figured it out. The next time I code, I will first use a pen and paper. @Holger That is exactly what I was doing wrong. It took me some time to realize it.